# How can I install the driver for rtl8192eu USB 2.0?

Tags: networking, drivers, software-installation, 21.10

I am using ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64

Please note that I don't have any networking capability at all in Linux.

So for example, to install anything I need to use Windows 10 to download the archive etc.

In order for the network to appear, you need to install the modem USB driver!

I downloaded the driver from here: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

I tried to execute the commands that I did in Arch Linux:

```
sudo make clean
sudo make
sudo make install
modprobe 8192eu
```

OR, I just use only: `sudo ./install` in folder file - to auto-install

But the system says that it cannot execute the command, because "compilers" are not installed, or something like that, to install the drivers that were unpacked from the archive into a folder.

What needs to be done to install the driver from local files, without a network? (well, or, using Windows 10, to download something there, and then just execute something in the terminal)

The device works in Debian and Arch.

I would appreciate detailed instructions, and please keep in mind that I have no way to access the internet from the system in question.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need at least the items in the `build-essential` meta package. I STRONGLY recommend that you find some way to connect your Linux system to the internet to install `build-essential` using APT. Perhaps you have a phone that you can tether to your device to access the phone's internet connection? Anyway, if you can't connect, the packages you need to download are probably `libc6-dev`, `gcc`, `g++`,  `make` and `dpkg-dev`.

You can download the deb packages for your version (make sure you get that right) from https://packages.ubuntu.com (use the search). For example, the `make` package can be downloaded from https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/make/download

You may also need `git`, `dkms` and the `linux-headers` package for your kernel (find the kernel version with `uname -r`).

Once you have these deb packages you can, in the directory where the files are, use `dpkg -i` to install them, like:

```
sudo dpkg -i name-of-deb-package.deb
```

After that, you can try compiling the driver again.

You might be in for a headache with this. It will be very much easier if you can connect the system to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for `realtek rtl8192eu` linux driver, then check packages that are available for other distributions:

1. `yum search realtek`
2. `yum install rtl-sdr`